# IE 8 showing previous background on text slide-in animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a real annoying problem and I can't seem to find it. Only in IE8, my jquery slide-in text animation background is showing the previous slide's main background, but only when sliding in(when the text animation pauses, the previous background disappears in the space of the animated text)

To see what I'm talking, please go to: http://lamininbeauty.co.za/index2.html. 
But what is strange, is that if you have IE 9, and you use IE8 browser and document  mode, you won't see the effect(I don't). I actually picked it up on an actual IE8 browser...

Any idea what is causing that ugly background effect when the text is sliding in?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, finally. the containing div of the background images is set to a fixed width of 1024px. I changed it to 100%, gave it another parent div which I then made width: 1024px. For some reason that fixed it...